# Cant use while loop because it is taking time is there any way faster way to get the final file..in linux

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep

```
cat file_1.txt

100 200 name

100 200

100 200

150 300

150 300

150 250

150 250

150 300 name


final file should be 

150 300

150 300

150 250

150 250
```

i am using this command

```
cat file_1.txt | grep -v "name">file_2.txt; cat file_2.txt| while read line;do cat file_1.txt| grep "$line"| head -1|grep -v "name" ;done
```

but data is too much cant use while loop it is taking to much time cat use while loop . is there any other way to do it fast 
like using `"grep -vf file_1 file_2"` something like that By passing like that  . please let me know.

here i am using the logic of getting the top most line of pattern found pattern is  every line of `"file_1.txt"`

Comment: Could you please use `code tags` when posting code. Also, it would be helpful if you could rephrase your question; because in its current state it is very hard to understand what it is you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that your code is printing out every line of file_1.txt unless either (a) the line contains `name` or (b) the first two columns of the line are the same as a previous line that contained `name`.  In that case, try:

```
$ awk '/name/{bad[$1,$2];next} !(($1,$2) in bad)' file_1.txt 
150 300
150 300
150 250
150 250
```

#### How it works

- `/name/{bad[$1,$2];next}`

  If the current line contains `name`, then we add an entry to the associative array `bad` under the key of the first two columns.  We then skip the rest of the commands and jump to start over on the `next` line.
- `!(($1,$2) in bad)`

  If the first two columns of the current line, `$1,$2` are *not* among the keys of `bad`, then print this line.

Comment: what to do if we dont know the exact column number inside the file is there any way to do it.

Comment: It is possible but it is likely to slow it down a lot.

Comment: is it possible with grep command ,improvise

Comment: What would these lines look like?