# Is there any faster way to get this output file in linux

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep

```
cat file_1

my colour is red
my rose is red
my colour is blue
my rose id blue

cat file_2 
red
blue

cat output_file should be
my colour is red
my colour is blue
```

here i am using

```
cat file_2 | while read line;do cat file_1 | grep "$line" | head -1;done
```

here i am trying to get the top most line containing the `pattern "red" and "blue"` which is present in the `file_2`

is there any other way  to do , `as fast as possible`, while loop is taking time

Comment: see also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Comment: Gosh, this looks a lot like [Can't use while loop because it is taking time. Is there any way faster way to get the final file in linux?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/312328/80216)

Comment: If you care about minimal execution time, why are you dropping useless `cat` processes into the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `while` construct to loop over the patterns from `file2` and then use `-m 1` with `grep` to stop after first match on `file1`:

```
while IFS= read -r i; do grep -Fm1 "$i" file1; done <file2
```

- `-F` treats the pattern literally
- `-m 1` makes `grep` to exit after first match

Shell loops are usually not efficient, but given the pattern list is small it is usable in this case.

**Faster alternative**, `xargs`:

```
xargs -a file2 -n1 -P2 -I'{}' grep -Fm1 {} file1
```

Use more parallel processes (`-P`) for more patterns.

**Example:**

```
% while IFS= read -r i; do grep -Fm1 "$i" file1; done <file2
my colour is red
my colour is blue

% xargs -a file2 -n1 -P2 -I'{}' grep -Fm1 {} file1
my colour is blue
my colour is red
```

Comment: my rose is red and my rose id blue lines using the same command

Answer (score 2):

To print the first line from file_1 that matches a line in file_2:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} {for (line in a) if ($0~line) {print; delete a[line]}}' file_2 file_1
my colour is red
my colour is blue
```

This approach reads through each file just once.

#### How it works

- `FNR==NR{a[$0];next}`

  This saves every line in file_2 as a key in associative array `a`.
- `for (line in a) if ($0~line) {print; delete a[line]}`

  For every line in file_1, we check to see if it matches a key in array `a`.  If it does, we print the line and delete the key.